# .NET Core Multi Tenancy practicality

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core, multi-tenant

I was wondering if it is practical to develop a .NET Core application to be multi tenanted or would having a normal single tenant application be sufficient?

My current db structure is as follows:

- Users Table
- Organization Table
- Product Table

A user belongs to an organization (with the exception of system administrators) and an organization can have multiple products

When a user logs in, part of their claims is the OrganizationId meaning they can only see Products that their OrganizationId owns.

At the moment, my urls look like this:

- www.localhost.com:9988
- www.localhost.com:9988/Products/Product/Create

My Startup.cs url routing looks like this:

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    routes.MapRoute(
      name: "areas",
      template: "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}"
    );
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "default",
        template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}"
    );

});
```

Would it be difficult to transform what I have now into a multi tenanted application? Something like when a User belonging to an Organization logs in, their url will be

> organizationname.localhost.com:9988/Products/Product

Or is my current method enough?

I intend on building it to support multiple organizations.

Comment: You can do it however you like. My personal preference, especially when using containers (and you should be using containers), is to make the tenancy config-based. In other words, you can deploy with an environment of "{orgname}-prod" for example, and then sub in entirely different config settings (connection strings, etc.). That way your app need only focus on supporting a generic organization in an abstract way. All the stuff that makes one org unique from another comes in via config.

Comment: When you say containers do you mean something like Docker? I'm trying to achieve something like what Shopify does. When you register, you get something like a subdomain using your shop name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We do something very similar to your theoretical setup currently. Same code runs for each tenant on their own 'server' (containerized). Most of the "difficulty" in the configuration should be related to the server rather than .Net itself.

Depending on your area of business you might want to determine if any clients might be upset that their data is commingled with other's. If it's not a big deal and just the logical (org) separation works ignore me on that.

Comment: I was thinking more along the lines of Shopify where you get something like a subdomain when you register?  e.g. myshopname.shopify.com. Would it be possible to create these tenants that are containerized programmatically? I have no experience with containers so I will have to learn them as well.

Comment: Yes. Not just with containers, but it'll make it far easier. The idea of a container is a self-contained unit that can be spun up or down and scaled independently. With orchestration (kubernetes) and a frontend proxy (HAProxy, Envoy, etc) or service mesh (Istio), you can easily map subdomains or paths to the pods (roughly the same as a container).

Comment: What @ChrisPratt said. I'm pretty new to the clould/containerization game myself, but a definite benefit seems to be the large number of infrastructure tasks that can be handled programmatically and largely hands-off - tasks like what you are considering here.

Comment: Thanks guys, I'll try doing some research on containers and see what i can come up with.